# How to perform Multiple write opeartion on a single file?

Tags: asp.net, file-io

I have a website in asp.net 2.0 which write some thing on a file. But at the same time if another user hit that site it does not work till the first one operation on the file completed after that second one can do operation with the files.
How to handle such situation.

```
            AppConfiguration appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration();
    string LogFile =String.Empty;
    string sLogFormat =string.Empty;
    string sErrorTime =string.Empty;
    StreamWriter sw=null;
    public LogManager()
    {

        if(!File.Exists(AppConfiguration.LogFilePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppConfiguration.LogFilePath);
        }

        LogFile = AppConfiguration.LogFilePath+"WAP"+sErrorTime + ".log";
        if(!File.Exists(LogFile))
        {
         File.Create(LogFile);
        }
    }

    public void closeStream()
    {
        if(sw != null)
        {
            sw.Close();
        }
    }

    public void LogException(string className,string methodName, string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!File.Exists(LogFile))
            {
                File.Create(LogFile);
            }

            sw = new StreamWriter(LogFile,true);

            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | " + className + ":" + methodName + ":"+ errorMessage);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            if(sw != null)
            {
                sw.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Sandy; the reason this is happening depends on your code. Can you share some of it with us?

Comment: You should replace your log file with a table in a SQL database.

Comment: No, wannna my logs in a flat file only.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring How to apply locks can you give me a example?

Comment: Do you have the option to keep the structure in memory for reading from? Then you could have atomic object-update-file-writes that aren't connected to the reading the object.

Comment: @Sandy: Two processes cannot write to the same file at once.  You should use a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than opening and closing the log file for every entry, you might consider having a single logging process (e.g. syslog or a separate logging thread) that keeps the log file open.

Answer (score -1):

Writing lines to a plain text file will mess it up if multiple users are going to handle it. Rather, you can use database to store / retrieve text. You can even provide a button somewhere to export the records to a plain text file if needed.

Comment: The OP has stated that they want to use flat files. Answering them by saying "Use a Database" is not really an answer to their question.

Comment: Add to this the fact that databases are hardly more efficient for this use case.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring Thanks for the lesson. At the time I posted the answer, Sandy didn't mention that he wants to use flat files only :|